# cTakes taking an extremely long time on 'MaxentParserWrapper - Starting Processing: .DS_Strore'

Tags: nlp, ctakes

I am trying to run cTakes and use the CPE implementation. I've followed the User Guide exactly, but when I run it (press the 'go' arrow) the process seems to get stuck on 'MaxentParserWrapper - Starting Processing: .DS_Strore' for a very long time. Is this a normal or does this suggest there is something misconfigured?

Comment: did you find any solution ? i am facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry for not seeing your questioN! I think my solution was too not use the UI provided and call the method directly